# WSO2 EI REST API Manager Resource

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I need to manage a Registry Resource deployed into the Enterprise Integrator.
Using the REST API like this:
https://localhost:9443/registry/resource/_system/governance/EstrattoContoEnti/xml/EstrattoContoEntiConf.xml

I can GET the resource, but...how can I modify this or create a new one?
Calling a PUT o POST I get Error 405 - Method Not Allowed.

Is there any API to manage the registry entries on the WSO2 EI?
Or may I need to use something else?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box via a REST API.
There is a AdminService for Registry and you may access that AdminService and get the related functionality via SOAP.
But in your case, since you are expecting a REST API, you can create a web-app client which will use this Admin-service, so that you have a REST API to the registry via this client.

There is already such a client written. Have a look at the steps on how to get this and configured from the following blog.

http://abeykoon.blogspot.com/2015/04/wso2-gov-registry-using-registry-api.html

Cheers.